# Finding the best linear section of data

Tags: python, regression, data-analysis, scientific-computing

I have some scientific data and wish to find the best region to fit a straight line in. Theoretically, the data should have a constant gradient but other influences effect the data such that there are non-linear sections as shown below

[image]

So far I've tried taking the second derivative and locate regions of zero value or having a moving window of 100 points that is fitted and select the region with minimum chi square. However, these haven't been able to select the region correctly. What is a method to select the best region of the data to fit with a straight line?

Comment: Take several smaller windows of points to get a idea where your ideal zone is. then start adding points before and after the window until your r2 drops below a certain threshold. This will give you a good idea of where your linear zone is. you can after that further refine by taking out outliers

Answer (score 0):

This is not, perhaps, an answer but was too long for a comment.

Here's a couple of ideas I've used for similar tasks.
I'm supposing we have data (x[],y[]) for i=i..N.

The least squares best fit line, x->a*x+b based on data with indices in S (a subset of {1,,N}) is

```
a = r; b = my(S) - r*mx(S)
```

where

```
r = C(S)/Vx(S)
mx(S) = Sum{ i in S | x[i]}/|S|
my(S) = Sum{ i in S | y[i]}/|S|
Vx(S) = Sum{ i in S | square(x[i]-mx(S))/|S|
Vy(S) = Sum{ i in S | square(y[i]-my(S))/|S|
C(S) = Sum{ i in S | (x[i]-mx(S))*(y[i]-my(S))/|S|
```

Moreover the 'average chisq' is

```
Sum{ i in S| square( y[i]-(a*x[i]+b))}/|S| = Vy(S)-C(S)*C(S)/Vx(S)
```

The fit for a union a union of two disjoint intervals S and T say can be calculated from the fits for S and T

```
mx(S union T) = (|S|*mx(S) + |T|*mx(T))/(|S|+|T|)
Vx(S union T) =  (|S|/(|S|+|T|))*Vx(S)
                +(|T|/(|S|+|T|))*Vx(T) 
                +|S|*|T|/square( |S|+|T|))*square( mx(S)-mx(T))
my(S union T) = (|S|*my(S) + |T|*my(T))/(|S|+|T|)
Vy(S union T) =  (|S|/(|S|+|T|))*Vy(S)
                +(|T|/(|S|+|T|))*Vy(T) 
                +|S|*|T|/square( |S|+|T|))*square( my(S)-my(T))
C(S union T) =  (|S|/(|S|+|T|))*C(S)
                +(|T|/(|S|+|T|))*C(T) 
                +|S|*|T|/square( |S|+|T|))*(mx(S)-mx(T))*(my(S)-my(T))
```

So, for example, if you follow Sembei's suggestion combining adjacent (or other) fits can be done very efficiently.

All of the formulae above can be derived with straightforward (though tedious) algebra.